# invalid_frame_end_marker error while publishing to RabbitMQ using .net client

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ .net client library to publish the messages to a RabbitMQ node in the following manner.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = "localhost",
                    Port = 5672,
                    UserName = "guest",
                    Password = "guest",
                    VirtualHost = @"/"
                };
_conn = factory.CreateConnection();

_channel = _conn.CreateModel();

_properties = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
```

And then the below is being called in a loop

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    formatter.Serialize(memStream, message);

    var properties = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    properties.Priority = Convert.ToByte((int) priority);

   _channel.BasicPublish(String.Empty, _routeKey, properties, memStream.ToArray());
 }
```

The above code is working fine with a medium load around 50-100 messages per second. But when I increase the number of messages to be published around 500 messages per second, the RabbitMQ node starts giving the below error and disconnects the channel.

```
Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=501, text="FRAME_ERROR - type 206, first 16 octets = <<31,0,60,0,40,0,0,6,115,101,110,115,111,114,16,115>>:
{invalid_frame_end_marker, 114}
", classId=0, methodId=0, cause=: 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelSend(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, Boolean immediate, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body) 
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.BasicPublish(String exchange, String routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body)`
```

The size of the message with BinaryFormatter is around 5kb.

Comment: which version are you using?  Do you use  `_channel` in more threads?

Comment: version 3.5.3 and I have just one thread writing into the message broker. What I have found is, when the node reaches the `vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio` threshold, then the error starts coming.

Comment: Perhaps open an issue here https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues or ask on our mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users @AnkitSaroch

Comment: I tested this https://gist.github.com/Gsantomaggio/ff11adbfcac4033cda5e without problems. I tried with and without priority queue. Could you post your full code, or a simple code with the problem? @AnkitSaroch

Comment: As commented above, we increased the `vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio`, to let the consumer have enough time to consume the messages when there is a spike in the number of messages published. So, I don't think that's code side problem but a configuration one.